NXP LPC55xx: I2C implementation hangs when SCL pulled down briefly - bug or feature?
I detected an odd behavior of the I2C implementation on LPC55xx MCUs (tested on LPC5526 and LPC5536).
In short:
When I introduce a glitch on the SCL line while there's no I2C transmission, the MCU's I2C stack hangs as busy after the next transmission is initiated.
In my setup, I have the MCU with the two I2C signals SDA and SCL connected to the respective pull-up resistors and nothing else is connected to the I2C bus (except a logic analyzer that is absolutely passive).
The MCU runs a simple I2C code example: On each keypress (over UART), the program reads a byte from an arbitrary I2C address and prints the result of the transfer. The expected result is a status that indicates that a NACK has been received (as the bus has no slaves/targets connected).
Now when I connect SCL to GND briefly (while the I2C bus is idle) and then press a key to initiate the next read transmission, the code never returns and hangs indefinitely.
Debugger shows that the I2C peripheral is in the state "progress" and cannot handle another command:

Is this expected behavior?
Links:

LPC5526 manual, as the LPC5536 manual is only available after registering at NXP.com


I'd lean towards feature.  An i2c slave can request more time, by holding the clock line low.  The feature is called clock stretching.

Thank you for your reply. However, it is my understanding that clock stretching pauses an ongoing transaction. In other words, clock stretching only occurs while the bus is busy, i.e., after a START condition and before the STOP condition. See section 3.1.9 in the standard. Here in my setup, the bus is free. Even if it were clock stretching, the SCL has been released and still the MCU's I2C implementation is stuck in "busy" mode.

Consider multi-master detection.

what  exactly do you mean with "multi-master detection"? Do you mean the arbitration procedure when two masters (controller) initiate a data transfer at the same time? That should be irrelevant here as in my setup the master is idle and does not handle any transactions when I pull down SCL manually. In this case, there's no need for arbitration in my opinion.
